# I changed the password complexity and now only administrators can log in windows server, what i can do?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, user-accounts

I there:

I changed the password complexity disabling it via a GPO and its included the server machine because i applied the GPO as a domain policies and now, only domain administrators can log into my windows server machine.

I tried disabling the GPO, enabling and turning it back and nothing works.

what i can do?.

ps: it is a test machine.

Comment: Did you allow for the time to the group policy to update before trying to log in again? If not, leave the policy as "Not Configured" and run gpupdate /force to force the policy to be enabled then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the GPO vice versa.

When a GPO is applied it will set the value until something changes it. If you are setting it to "Not Configured" the GPO-engine will only skip to set it... and therefore the old value will still be there.